# What do double square brackets around "position" mean in the Metal language?

Tags: syntax, metal

What does `float4 position [[position]];` do in the following snippet?

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

struct Vertex
{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float4 color;
};

vertex Vertex vertex_main(device Vertex *vertices [[buffer(0)]], uint vid [[vertex_id]])
{
    return vertices[vid];
}
```

I am confused by the `[[position]]` part and similar usage in the function definition especially.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I believe you should be looking at metal shader syntax rather than Objective-C.

Comment: this is C++ syntax not Objective-C. MSL is based on C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Metal Shading Language is documented at https://developer.apple.com/metal/metal-shading-language-specification.pdf

In particular look at "Table 9" on page 68 of that document. There [[position]] is identified as an attribute qualifier for the return type of a Vertex Function.  I assume that means that when your vertex shader returns the caller will use the values in that part of the struct to determine the positions of the vertices the shader would like to modify.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link! Now I understand there is some more to it then just the syntax.
However, like I understand int a[5] creates/means an array of size 5 in memory.
So, similarly going by just the syntax, what does [[ ]] do/mean ? Does this kind of initialization have a name to it?

Comment: I can only go by what I read in the document above and what I know of shading languages.  The [[ ]] syntax identifies an "attribute" for the entity it is attached to.  Meta-information about the variable or field that is meaningful for what role it plays in the shader.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to respond to your comment regarding the name of the brackets, but the [[]] brackets are attribute syntax taken from C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Metal is based on C++ and the this is just the syntax of attributes in C++11. See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) for more details about the grammar.